# Providing credentials to arcpy.conversion.WFSToFeatureClass()

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, wfs, authentication

I need to pull in some data from a Web Feature Service (WFS), into a local feature class/file geodatabase.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/wfs-to-feature-class.htm

`arcpy.conversion.WFSToFeatureClass(input_WFS_server, WFS_feature_type, out_path, out_name, {is_complex}, {max_features}, {expose_metadata}, {swap_xy})`

But this WFS source service that I am using, needs authentication.

How do I provide those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the admin provide a key that you can add to the end of the URL, something that looks like this:

```
https://gis.somewebsite.com/geoserver/wfs?authkey=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234567890...
```

Comment: Is that literally the only way? I'm just figuring that if the origin of the service are totally invisible to me, but I can read the service, why would I not be able to download the content?

Comment: No, it's not, but it's the easiest way, if the admins provide access to a key generator for your account. Other ways are listed here: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#username-password-authentication
If you want to build it programatically, those resources can be discovered from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication